# Basis for the intersection of vector spaces

Tags: linear-algebra, vector, intersection

The MuPAD Notebook Interface provides the `linalg::intBasis` function:
http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/mupad_ref/linalg-intbasis.html

How can I get the same functionality in Mathematica?

There exists an old thread called "Intersection of two vector spaces":
[Intersection of two vector spaces](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/60306/intersection-of-two-vector-spaces)
However, I am searching for a general solution which works with any number of vector spaces (like the `linalg::intBasis` does), not just two.

Moreover, the solution given in this old thread misbehaves in many cases (that I tried).

For three vector spaces I tried `getIntersection[V1, getIntersection[V2, V3]]` but it returned an incorrect result (where V1, V2 and V3 come from the "Example 1" from the `linalg::intBasis` web link given above).

Also, if I try `getIntersection[V1, V1]` it happily returns the `{0, 0}` vector among the basis vectors.

Additionally, the first comment (by Daniel Lichtblau) in the first "Answer" in this old thread says that one can also use `coeffs=ker[[All,1;;n]]; ker.coeffs` but the `ker.coeffs` part often generates an error: `Dot::dotsh: Tensors {...} and {...} have incompatible shapes.`

(Note: I'm a newcomer here and apparently I have no way to post "comments" in threads which do not belong to me as I get an error saying "You must have 50 reputation to comment" and my "answers" there get deleted. So, I am unable to report problems which I find in them.)

**Update (2019.08.07)**: I have been using the code provided here for several years now. I have found that in some cases, especially when dealing with inexact numerical matrices, it could misbehave. I finally decided to do something about it and, with the help provided in [this thread](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/203133/deletecases-pattern-which-applies-chop-to-all-elements), I came out with this improved function, which may be useful for a casual trespasser who reads this. Note that the `Chop` function uses a default tolerance of `10.^(-10)` but, you can easily change it in the `getIntersectionBasis` below, e.g.: use `Chop[FullSimplify[#], 1.*^-14]` (for a tolerance of `10.^(-14)`).

```
getIntersectionBasis[] := {}
getIntersectionBasis[{}] := {}
getIntersectionBasis[{}, __] := {}
getIntersectionBasis[__, {}] := {}
getIntersectionBasis[l1_] := getIntersectionBasis[l1, l1]
getIntersectionBasis[l1_, l2_, l3__] := 
  getIntersectionBasis[l1, getIntersectionBasis[l2, l3]]
getIntersectionBasis[l1_, l2_] := 
  Catch[With[{ker = FullSimplify[NullSpace[FullSimplify[Transpose[Join[l1, l2]]], ZeroTest->(PossibleZeroQ[Chop[FullSimplify[#]]]&)]]}, 
    If[ker === {}, Throw[{}], 
      DeleteCases[FullSimplify[RowReduce[FullSimplify[ker[[All, 1 ;; Length[l1]]].l1], ZeroTest->(PossibleZeroQ[Chop[FullSimplify[#]]]&)]], {__?(PossibleZeroQ[Chop[FullSimplify[#]]]&)}]]] 
  ]
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to Mathematica.SE, please consider taking the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) so you learn the basics of the site. Once you gain enough reputation by making [good questions](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) you will be able to vote up and down both questions and answers. When you see good ones, please vote them up by clicking the grey triangles, because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. As you receive help, try to give it too, by *answering questions* in your area of expertise.

Comment: @Wile E. I see that you *have* posted a question but that it was closed.  Please [edit](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/posts/64165/edit) your question and explain why it is not a duplicate of the [linked one.](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/60306/intersection-of-two-vector-spaces)  After you do so I will be glad to reopen it.

Comment: Regarding the inexact case, one might use the `Tolerance` option in `NullSpace`.

Comment: Thanks. I did try `Tolerance` and it never helped (in cases in which I had problems with `getIntersectionBasis`). Adding `ZeroTest` solved the problem (at least in the majority of cases). I still have matrices of "exact" complex values for which `NullSpace` is unable to deliver the result (in these cases I need to apply `N` and calculate it numerically).

Answer (score 2):

You'd need to row reduce the intersection set to remove linear dependencies it might have. The code below should handle this.

```
getIntersectionBasis[] := {}
getIntersectionBasis[{}] := {}
getIntersectionBasis[{}, __] := {}
getIntersectionBasis[__, {}] := {}
getIntersectionBasis[l1_] := getIntersectionBasis[l1, l1]
getIntersectionBasis[l1_, l2_, l3__] := 
  getIntersectionBasis[getIntersectionBasis[l1, l2], l3]
getIntersectionBasis[l1_, l2_] := 
  Catch[With[{ker = NullSpace[Transpose[Join[l1, l2]]]}, 
    If[ker === {}, Throw[{}], 
      DeleteCases[RowReduce[ker[[All, 1 ;; Length[l1]]].l1], {0 ..}]]]]
```

Now fill in your favorite example (which actually belongs in the question).

Comment: Thanks for your help. However, it seems to me that, when playing with V1, V2, V3 mentioned above, no matter what I try, the new `getIntersectionBasis` always returns `{{1, 0}, {0, 1}}`

Comment: What's wrong with that result?

Comment: Another problem is that when I try the "Example 2" from the `linalg::intBasis` web link given above, `getIntersectionBasis[S1, S2]` returns `Dot::dotsh: "Tensors {} and {{1,0,1,0},{0,1,0,1}} have incompatible shapes."`.

Comment: I'll have a look at that second one. As for the first, well, a basis is not unique. Once we bring in row echelon form (via `RowReduce`) one is likely to get a result of the sort you are seeing.

Comment: Okay, I had a look. It is a case where the basis is empty. Would it be maybe possible to patch the code to handle that edge case? (Yes, I can fix it. But is it really so much of a problem?)

Comment: Also, a general rule of thunb: if you want examples tested, include them, in cut-and-paste form, in the query. Not as a link to code posted in a different language.

Comment: Unfortunaltely you are right that there can be different bases. Apparently MuPAD reuses user's vectors (if possible). I'll maybe try to "collect" some "test cases" and make a table with results coming from some different algebra systems.

Comment: I've got two questions. (1.) In the old "Intersection of two vector spaces" thread, the author says that the algorithm is only valid in cases when "l1" is shorter than "l2". As the new `getIntersectionBasis` function is based on the same algorithm, is it also affected by the same limitation? (2.) One can define `getIntersectionBasis[l1_, l2_, l3__] := getIntersectionBasis[getIntersectionBasis[l1, l2], l3]` or  `getIntersectionBasis[l1_, l2_, l3__] := getIntersectionBasis[l1, getIntersectionBasis[l2, l3]]` and I wonder which version is better and why.

Comment: (1) The new code, using RowReduce to get a "correct" basis, should obviate any issue with relative lengths. (2) Either one might fare better or worse, depending on which order pares down dimension faster. The smart thing might be to just sort the arguments and work from smallest to largest in number of vectors per list.