# DeleteCases pattern which applies Chop to all elements

Tags: pattern-matching, filtering

In my current macro, I have:

```
DeleteCases[Chop[FullSimplify[RowReduce[something]]], {0 ..}]
```

This works fine for both, exact and numeric complex numbers (with modules of the order of 1 at most) in my "something".

However, the returned result is "`Chop`-ped", of course.

I would like to get the full precision (for all elements) also in numeric cases.
I tried to use:

```
DeleteCases[RowReduce[something], {x_..}/;PossibleZeroQ[Chop[FullSimplify[x]]]]
```

This works fine as long as long as all "`x`" (in a "row") are exactly equal.
So, e.g. it does remove `{1.*^-11, 1.*^-11}` but unfortunately it does not remove `{0, 1*.^-11}` nor `{1.*^-11, 0}`.

Could you, please, help me with it.

**Update (2019.08.05)**: Thank you very much for all your neat examples. I decided to use (I hope it really does what I "intend" it to do):

```
DeleteCases[FullSimplify[RowReduce[FullSimplify[something], ZeroTest->(PossibleZeroQ[Chop[FullSimplify[#]]]&)]], {__?(PossibleZeroQ[Chop[FullSimplify[#]]]&)}]
```

Solutions based on `Pick` have two problems for me. First, they completely remove "rows" with empty lists (i.e. `{}`). Second, the very first step is `Chop`, which unconditionally evaluates all elements of all "rows" while, in the solution based on `DeleteCases`, the `{__?(TrueOrFalse[#]&)}` pattern will evaluate elements of each "row" only until the first one that returns "False" (at least that's how I imagine it works). Also, the solution which uses `Total` would need an additional `Abs` inside, otherwise it completely removes "rows" which elements sum up to 0 (e.g. `{-1, 1}`).

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend this type of solution:

```
notChopped = FullSimplify[RowReduce[something]];
keep = Not@*MatchQ[{0 ..}] /@ Chop[notChopped];
Pick[notChopped, keep]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can  use `DeleteCases`  with the pattern `{__?(PossibleZeroQ @*Chop)}` in the second argument:

```
lst = {{2., 1., 0}, {1.*^-11, 1.*^-11} , {0, 1.*^-11} , {1.*^-11, 0}}; 

DeleteCases[lst, {__?(PossibleZeroQ @*Chop)}]
```

> {{2., 1., 0}}

And alternative ways to use `Pick`:

```
Pick[lst, Unitize @ Total[Chop @ lst, {2}], 1]
```

> {{2., 1., 0}}

```
Pick[lst, Nand @@@ PossibleZeroQ @ Chop[lst]]
```

> {{2., 1., 0}}